# Cannot open Katalon project file (cannot be selected)

Tags: katalon-studio

Yesterday upgraded to Katalon 5.8.6 and since then I am not able to open the project file. When I navigate to File/Open Project and locate the project file, I cannot select it. It appears like an invisible file. However, I can open the same file with other apps such as Atom.

My colleague also upgraded with me to 5.8.6 but he can open the project. The only difference - I am using a Mac and he has a Windows machine.

I uninstalled Katalon from my machine and installed an older version using "https://download.katalon.com/x.x.x/Katalon_Studio.dmg" where x.x.x is the version number for Katalon. I tried with 5.8.5 and 5.8.0 but I get the same result - cannot even select the file.

It is worth mentioning that the migrated version in the .prj file is showing 5.7.0 even after my upgrades to later versions (5.7.0). I tried updating it to the version I am using (at the current time this is 5.8.6) but that did not help.

Before the upgrade I was on 5.8.5 and everything was fine (Monday was my last commit to the project). I know some people might point at potential git issues, but my colleague and I have been working on this project for some time and we have never had git issues.

Attaching a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htcnB.jpg)

Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

In that case, You need to select `project folder` not, the `.prj` file.

If you go through the web page here with the sub heading [Open an existing test project](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/manage-test-project.html#open-an-existing-test-project) it says,

> Select File -> Open Project from the menu. Browse to the folder where your project is located and select it.